# two column document figure over entire page

Tags: floats, multicol, matlab

I have a document with two columns, I want to insert a figure that is as wide as the entire page (not only in one column).

my figure is a matlab graphic in `.eps` format.
I use `\usepackage{multicol} {2}` for the columns.
I have inserted my figure using

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=18cm]{figures/subplotting3.eps}
\caption{text}
\label{fig:text}
\end{figure}
```

so far so good, however the figure is not 18cm wide (18cm = page without borders) and the font of the axis of the figure shrinks! I have set the font style to 10pt in matlab

I need to understand how to import such figures from matlab without getting smaller fonts and having it on the same wide as the page. I guess the method of setting the width of the figure to 18cm manually is not the correct way to do it. Do I need some additional packages?
[image]

Comment: try to use `figure*` ! For further help, please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can compile as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include the complete LaTeX code next time, with the class and packages you use, to help produce a response that meets your requirements. Here I just use the code from your former question.

Your snippet works, but the wide figure will be set on the next page.

A smaller figure, with a less than a column width will do fine.

Try this code.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % from previuos question
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}

\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section*{Abstract \protect\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract} }
    \kant[1]
    \newpage    
    \section{Introduction}      
    \kant[2]

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \caption{text}
        \label{fig:text}
    \end{figure}

    \kant[12-13]
    \newpage  
    \section{Basics}
    \kant[4-6]  
\end{multicols} 


\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\caption{text}
\label{fig:text}
\end{figure*}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \kant[7-9]
        \newpage
        \section*{Appendix \protect\markboth{Appendix}{Appendix}}
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Notice that the `multicols` environment was interrupted to allow the insertion of the figure at a particular place.

To correct the fonts of an exported MATLAB figure, you should try

**1.** Change the MATLAB figure configuration  settings until you get the correct combinations of image width, font  and fontsize that will look good in your LateX document. (If possible use the same sf font of the main document).

I haven't used MATLAB for a long time so I can't help here.

**2.** Use an .eps (vector) editor such as Inkscape to **add** or correct the axis labels and other references. It is very good software and it is free. Recommended!!

I found this old recipe in my archive. Probably from an older forum. I guess there are much better tools now.

> Create the graph of a MATLAB figure and inspect it on the screen,
> until is exactly the way you want it to appear in your document. Save
> the figure as .pdf or .png using `export_fig` at full resolution (600
> dpi). `export_fig` will respect the dimensions of the figure and embed
> fonts, producing high-quality  bitmaps.

Take a look at the File Exchange

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange?q=export+to+figure++latex

[image: wide]

[image: small]

**UPDATE**

To put the figure on the same page after the text in two columns:

1 The text must be shorter, that is, the two columns must end in a
suitable place to leave enough space for the figure.

2 Then, issue a `\clearpage` after the environment in the figure to flush the
floats.

3 LaTeX will place the floats on the top of the page. (SOP)

See the updated answer.

To put the figure exactly where you want, against all LaTeX wishes, with your setup, well ... I think it deserves another question!

There are many possible solutions. Search the topic in this forum.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol} 

\usepackage{float}      

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % from previuos question
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\rmfamily \small \nouppercase \leftmark}

\setlength{\headsep}{.5cm}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section*{Abstract \protect\markboth{Abstract}{Abstract} }
    \kant[1]
    \newpage    
    \section{Introduction}      
    \kant[2]

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-grid-100x100pt}
        \caption{text}
        \label{fig:text}
    \end{figure}    

    \kant[12-13]
    \newpage  
    \section{Basics}
    \kant[4]    
\end{multicols}     
\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
\caption{text}
\label{fig:texti}
\end{figure*}
\clearpage

    \begin{multicols}{2}        
        \kant[7-9]
        \newpage
        \section*{Appendix \protect\markboth{Appendix}{Appendix}}
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: floater]

Using the `caption` package and without using the figure environment

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A} 
    \label{fig:texti}
    \captionof{figure}{text}
\end{center}
```

you will get

[image: no float]

Comment: thank you very much for this clear answer.
Just one more thing, what do I do if I want to have first the text in two columns and on the same page (after the text) my figure over both columns. Same as your screenshot with the figure A just vis-a-versa

Comment: @caarloXY See my updated answer.