# How to allow minimum blank space on the top and bottom of an image in latex?

Tags: spacing, templates

[image]I wanted to insert a figure in a 2-column article where article class is elsarticle.cls.

I used the following code. But the problem is that the figure goes in a page and there exists blank white space in the top and bottom of the image file. I want to keep minimum blank space around the image. Please help me.

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{blindtext, graphicx, amsmath, algorithm, algpseudocode, pifont, 
algcompatible, comment, layout, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, filecolor=black, urlcolor=cyan, }
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=newline}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=period}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\journal{ICT Express}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Submission Guideline for ICT Express}
\author{Author’s Full Name 1\corref{cor1}}
\ead{author1@ictexpress.com}
\author{Author’s Full Name 2}
\ead{author2@ictexpress.com}
\author{Author’s Full Name 3}
\ead{author3@ictexpress.com}
\address{Department, Organization, City, Country\\Department, Organization, 
City, Country\\Department, Organization, City, Country}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\begin{abstract}
Texts...
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
abc \sep def \sep xyz
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}
Texts...
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2\columnwidth]{image.png}
\caption{Collected image from wikipedia}
\label{fig:ex}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you haven't really given enough information to allow anyone to answer but I would guess that the figure was placed on a float page (so no text other than figures) by default they are vertically centred so have space top and bottom.

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle. The details of my file is here...https://www.overleaf.com/read/snvrfqxzvbbm

Comment: You should make a small self contained example on this page. Your question is archived forever and will not make sense if you edit the overleaf file. that file is showing a red 13errors, after any error do not even look at the pdf except possibly for debugging, the pdf output is not intended to be usable after an error.

Comment: @David Carlisle, I am sorry for the inconvenience. I have edited the question file. Actually I am a new user.

Comment: with `figure*` as you have it the figure will necessarily come on a page on its own, so you can not set any values to reduce the space the white space is simply the difference between the size of the page and the size of the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest replacing the class's twocolumn option with the `multicol` package.

You have to start and finish the `multicols`  environments  in the right places to allow the wide figure to fit.

I added dummy text to simulate a more realistic scenario.

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}

% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{blindtext, graphicx, amsmath, algorithm, algpseudocode, pifont, 
algcompatible, comment, layout, amsthm, amssymb}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{ colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, filecolor=black, urlcolor=cyan, }
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck = false}
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=newline}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep=period}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\journal{ICT Express}

\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
    \title{Submission Guideline for ICT Express}
    \author{Author’s Full Name 1\corref{cor1}}
    \ead{author1@ictexpress.com}
    \author{Author’s Full Name 2}
    \ead{author2@ictexpress.com}
    \author{Author’s Full Name 3}
    \ead{author3@ictexpress.com}
    \address{Department, Organization, City, Country\\Department, Organization, 
    City, Country\\Department, Organization, City, Country}
    \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
    \begin{abstract}
        Texts...
    \end{abstract}
    \begin{keyword}
        abc \sep def \sep xyz
    \end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec1}  
    \blindtext[4]
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-A}
    \caption{Collected image from wikipedia}
    \label{fig:ex}
\end{figure*}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Other section}
    \blindtext[2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

There is a recent  Q&A  on the same topic, different class.

[two column document figure over entire page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567393/two-column-document-figure-over-entire-page/567412#567412)